# Parsing dates in pandas.read_csv with null-value handling?

Tags: python, pandas, null

Consider the following made-up CSV:

```
from io import StringIO

data = """value,date
7,null
7,10/18/2008
621,(null)"""

fake_file = StringIO(data)
```

I want to read this file using `pandas.read_csv`, handling nulls with the `na_values` parameter and dates with `parse_dates` and `date_parser`:

```
import pandas as pd

date_parser = lambda c: pd.datetime.strptime(c, '%m/%d/%Y')

df = pd.read_csv(fake_file,
                 parse_dates=['date'],
                 date_parser=date_parser,
                 na_values=['null', '(null)'])
```

Running this code in Python 3.5 gives me this:

```
  File "<ipython-input-11-aa5bcf0858b7>", line 1, in <lambda>
    date_parser = lambda c: pd.datetime.strptime(c, DATE_FMT)

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float
```

So it seems the nulls are handled first and then the dates are attempted to be parsed...

I know I can do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fake_file,
                 na_values=['null', '(null)'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],
                            format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

But my real question is how to both handle date formatting and `NaN`-handling in one fell swoop...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `format` and `errors='coerce'`:

```
date_parser = lambda c: pd.to_datetime(c, format='%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')
df = pd.read_csv(fake_file, parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=date_parser)
print (df)
   value       date
0      7        NaT
1      7 2008-10-18
2    621        NaT
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your custom date parser - it can't handle the `NaN`s. Instead you can use the `pandas.to_datetime` function as a parser:

```
from functools import partial

date_parser = partial(pd.to_datetime, format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 3):

Make use of [`infer_datetime_format=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter:

```
In [24]: pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=['date'], infer_datetime_format=True, na_values=['null', '(null)'])
Out[24]:
   value       date
0      7        NaT
1      7 2008-10-18
2    621        NaT
```

PS I guess your second option might be faster

Comment: Yeah, that does work. In reality, my date time format is this: `'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'`. Do you think `infer_datetime_format` could pick that up?

Comment: Dunno why I posted that without checking... It worked just fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`pd.to_datetime` can handle `NaN` by default, so, you simply need to replace the `date_parser` that you created with `pd.to_datetime`.

Here's how the solution looks like:

```
In [10]: pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO(data), parse_dates=['date'], 
    ...:             date_parser=pd.to_datetime, na_values=['null', '(null)'])
Out[10]: 
   value       date
0      7        NaT
1      7 2008-10-18
2    621        NaT
```